# Does Awk support regular expression quantifiers \{m,n\} or \{m\} or \{m,\}?

Tags: regex, awk

I am looking to print all the columns in a file that can contain a 10 digit mobile number

I tried this:

```
awk '/[0-9]\{10\}/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/[0-9]\{10\}/)print $i}' filename
```

but this sems to be not working.

I want to do it only using Awk

Eg text in a file

```
named 9898664511 nameb \n
namea nameb namec 7788992121 \n
namec named 7665544213 named \n
namea namec namef nameg namek 9090876534\n
```

Comment: I want to do it only using awk

Comment: Type `awk --version` in your console, put the output in your question.

Comment: Who voted to close for `general computing hardware and software` lol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does in GNU awk! Only that you don't have to escape them:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{v=10; if (v~/10{2}/) print "yes"}'

$ awk 'BEGIN{v=100; if (v~/10{2}/) print "yes"}'
yes
```

So your regular expression should be like this instead:

```
/[0-9]{10}/
```

Given your sample input, it would yield this:

```
$ awk '/[0-9]{10}/ {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /[0-9]{10}/) print $i}' n
9898664511
7788992121
7665544213
9090876534\n
```

So it may be a good idea to use the beginning `^` and end of line `$` characters to match those fields consisting in *exactly* 10 numbers:

```
$ awk '/[0-9]{10}/ {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{10}$/) print $i}' n
9898664511
7788992121
7665544213
```

From [The GNU Awk User’s Guide → 3.3 Regular Expression Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Operators):

> **{n}**
>
> **{n,}**
>
> **{n,m}**
>
> One or two numbers inside braces denote an interval expression. If there is one number in the braces, the preceding regexp is repeated n times. If there are two numbers separated by a comma, the preceding regexp is repeated n to m times. If there is one number followed by a comma, then the preceding regexp is repeated at least n times:
>
> ```
> wh{3}y
> ```
>
> Matches ‘whhhy’, but not ‘why’ or ‘whhhhy’.
>
> ```
> wh{3,5}y
> ```
>
> Matches ‘whhhy’, ‘whhhhy’, or ‘whhhhhy’ only.
>
> ```
> wh{2,}y
> ```
>
> Matches ‘whhy’, ‘whhhy’, and so on.
>
> **Interval expressions were not traditionally available in awk. They were added as part of the POSIX standard to make awk and egrep consistent with each other.**
>
> Initially, because old programs may use ‘{’ and ‘}’ in regexp constants, gawk did not match interval expressions in regexps.
>
> However, beginning with version 4.0, gawk does match interval expressions by default. This is because compatibility with POSIX has become more important to most gawk users than compatibility with old programs.
>
> For programs that use ‘{’ and ‘}’ in regexp constants, it is good practice to always escape them with a backslash. Then the regexp constants are valid and work the way you want them to, using any version of awk.16
>
> Finally, when ‘{’ and ‘}’ appear in regexp constants in a way that cannot be interpreted as an interval expression (such as /q{a}/), then they stand for themselves.

Comment: I tried awk '/[0-9]{10}/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~ /[0-9]{10}/)print $i}' filename

Comment: are you in GNU awk? Also, please provide a [mcve] in your question. Edit it to reflect so.

Comment: I tried this awk '/[0-9]{10}/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~ /[0-9]{10}/)print $i}' filename . but got nothing in the output

Comment: @user3369871 see my updated answer. Also, please provide the version of awk you are using.

Comment: @user3369871 You probably have an old version of GNU awk before 4.0, use the `--re-interval` flag

Comment: yes I used /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead and that works expected , thanks

Comment: RE Intervals aren't `gawk`-specific, they're POSIX in EREs. Any POSIX `awk` will support them. The reason `sed` needs to escape them is that sed supports BREs by default, not EREs, so you need to escape ERE metacharacters to activate them as such in `sed` scripts. Older versions of GNU awk didn't support them by default for backwards compatibility with older awk scripts (where `/a{2}/` meant literally `"a{2}"` not `"aa"`) but as POSIX evolved so did `gawk`. Other old awks (e.g. the very poorly named "New AWK", `nawk`) are not POSIX compatible and do not support them.